# What is this closed question lacking in clarity?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[What can cause voltage irregularities across an IC chip?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542993/what-can-cause-voltage-irregularities-across-an-ic-chip)

The question seems to me straightforward and answerable, though since only one person tried I understand there is a problem with it.  Probably because I wrote it, I can't see what the problem is.

It was meant to be a general question and not help-me-fix-my-specific-problem, as I assume the latter to be inappropriate for this site.

Should I have left out all the specific circuit context?  Or should I have done the opposite and explicitly made it about my specific problem and put in lots of details about that?

Or is it something else that the "details and clarity" closing reason is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at the question the first time around, I thought it needed more clarity, looking at it in detail I must have made an error. I'll reopen it, if you need something reopened just glad the question and send a message with the flag and a mod look at it